# GCM Activity getting force closed

Tags: android, error-handling, google-cloud-messaging

I am a beginner with Google cloud messaging. I was developing a demo app to check the functionality of GCm. I have created a GCM project and i am checking whether the device is registered or not. I am using the following code,

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
        if (regId.equals("")) {
          GCMRegistrar.register(this, "483910217912");
          Log.d(tag, "Registered");
        } else {
          Log.v(tag, "Already registered");
        }
    }
```

and my Manifest file is,

```
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<permission android:name="my_app_package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="my_app_package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
    <category android:name="my_app_package" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
        <activity
            android:name=".GCmExampleActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

I have included the gsm jar files into my project.

The Logcat error it gives is,

```
10-11 13:44:59.001: E/AndroidRuntime(339): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kochar.it.GCM/com.kochar.it.GCM.GCmExampleActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Device does not have package com.google.android.gsf
```

The error is on the line,

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're using the wrong emulator. The default emulator uses a regular Android emulator that doesn't have any Google packages and can't run all sorts of things like maps, c2dm and all sorts of stuff like that. What you want to do, is create a new emulator that can support the Google APIs.

Comment: thanx, it worked. i have created a new emulator that supports google api's. can you suggest some ideas about what types of project should i start with.!

Comment: Not getting your mean from saying "what types of project should i start with."

Comment: i was directed by my TL to study and create a demo app with GCM. now i dont know what next should i do. I just know dat i have to create server for this. but how, any tutorial link will help.

Comment: go with this [Getting started with GCM](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html)

Answer (score 2):

Don't run this in an emulator. Because it needs Google account.

Try one of below,

1. Create Emulator with Google api
   [image]
2. Run it on real android phones
3. Run it on Bluestack (http://bluestacks.com/)

It will solve your problem. :)

Comment: thanx, it worked. i have created a new emulator that supports google api's.